# Singleton class with custom initializer

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

In a Swift project, I have a class should be used as a `singleton`:

```
  class NearFieldManager : NSObject{
  static let shared = NearFieldManager()
  var dataToTransfer:Any!
 }
```

This class helps me communicate between several nearby devices and the `dataToTransfer` is some information each device is advertising about itself.
What makes me wondering about this class is that each time I call it goes like this:

```
let manager = NearFieldManager.shared
shared.dataToTransfer = "some data"
```

First, I am creating a reference to the manager and line after it I set some value on its property. How can I improve this design?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `dataToTransfer` is always the same for a specific device, you can create this data in `init()`

```
class NearFieldManager {
    static let shared = NearFieldManager()
    private let dataToTransfer: Any

    private init() { //private to forbid instantiation 
        self.dataToTransfer = methodToCreateDeviceData()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd get rid of that redundant `dataToTransfer` local var. It doesn't contribute anything but visual clutter.

Comment: @Alexander agree.